# Finding an equation to connect the max number of possible points

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, compression, point

I would like to find a way, given a set of any points on a 2 dimensional (or 3 dimensional if possible) plane, to connect as many of these points as possible with an equation, preferably in the form of X^n+BX^n and so on. X being of course a variable, and b and n being any numbers.

This would hopefully work in a way that given say, 50 random points, I would be able to use the equation to draw a line that would pass through as many of these points as possible.

I plan on using this in a compression format where data is converted to X,Y coordinate pairs, the goal is then to create equations that can reproduce these points. The equation would then be stored and the data would be replaced with a pointer to the equation as well as the number to enter into the equation to get the data back.

Any feedback is nice, this is just an idea I thought of during class and wanted to see if it would be possible to implement in a usable format.

Comment: If your data fits a "simple" curve (not many coefficients, not many bits needed to specify each coefficient) then you'll get good compression.  But even if that's not the case, this idea is still useful in the "other direction": if you start with n points evenly spaced along the x axis, fit a degree-(n-1) polynomial through them, and then sample the y values of that curve at n+k evenly-spaced positions along the x axis for some k >= 1, you can now lose any k of those n+k values *and still reconstruct the original n* :)  I believe this is the basis of Reed-Solomon error correction.

Answer (score 2):

To connect `n` points you need a polynomial of at most degree `n-1`. You can use [Polynomial Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) to form your line.

Comment: +1.  One point (heh) though: a polynomial can't go through 2 different points with the same x value.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Good point... The person who asked the question did ask for a polynomial though... :/